# Find if any columns that contain null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I new to SQL, I am having some difficulty solving this problem.

I want to write the select query which returns all those rows which have the null value in it.

I have more than 50 columns on the table and can be added some extra column it and because of that I getting difficult to write where condition.

AFAIK we can use `is null` but I don't want to repeat it for that much columns.

Please help me solve it. Let me know if any additional information required.

Comment: you *have* to give all columns in the where clause.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL to generate the where clause automatically. Otherwise, you're out of luck - you need to specify it for all columns that allow nulls. That said, I'm unsure why a table would ever need 50 columns and why you'd need to check whether any of them are null; my guess is that the design of the table is not optimal in the first place.

Comment: This is where design comes into play. Where does the null values come from? Why is an unknown impacting all 50 columns? If you could not enforce a NOT NULL as a column constraint,   how does your table even make 1NF, let alone 2NF (normalization). Is this a Fact or dimension table? What question(s) answered from this query?

Comment: I know it might seem trite, but in a relational theory the query solves mysteries, not simply states facts. Unless you know what columns in advance might contain nulls, or this is in an ETL conversion, your predicate (WHERE, ON, HAVING) is going to be odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this dynamic SQL query. This query will return row if any column contain null value.

```
DECLARE @tb NVARCHAR(255) = N'dbo.[tablename]';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tb
    + ' WHERE 1 = 0';

SELECT @sql += N' OR ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' IS NULL'
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tb)
      AND [is_nullable]=1;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: And destroy the poor optimizer which will likely just do something insane with the query.

Comment: Note that using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way (in that it doesn't require listing the columns explicitly) is

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
SELECT *
FROM   t1 x
WHERE  (SELECT x.*
        FOR xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
        ).exist('(//*/@ns:nil)') = 1
```

Though it does have the completely unneeded overhead of converting to XML.
http://rextester.com/VTV64079

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the whys and why-was-design-so-neglected-until-now questions, there are a number of alternatives.

Sadly, unless you can guarantee some of those 50+ columns might be empty, you are either going to use an complicated predicate or tables scans.

Since this is clearly not going to be able to use a predicate cleanly, use a clean table scan to test the values and run an inner join that match the boolean statement.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT IIF (col1 IS NULL, 1, (IIF(col2 IS NULL, 1, etc) ) ) as FOUND -- if clears, return 0
FROM TABLEA AS A)

SELECT A.*
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN TABLEA AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.FOUND = 1
```

This way `SQL Server` can treat it relationally and your predicate is clean. The `IIF` statement just compares one rows values with the check for `NULL` value (i would test alternate ways of declaring this to learn how the functions can vary), which significantly less complicated than trying to use the predicate in a complicated 50! Logical nightmare.

The key advantage to the inline function is that they are likely to be optimized sonce they were designed to deal cursively with data, whereas your predicate is for relational comparisons (SARGs)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: replace table_name with your table

```
DECLARE @COLNAME VARCHAR(MAX),@QUERY VARCHAR(MAX),@TABLE VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TEST TABLE(ID INT)
DECLARE @NULLS TABLE([TABLE] VARCHAR(MAX), [COLUMN] VARCHAR(MAX),[HAS_NULL] VARCHAR(MAX))
SET @TABLE='TABLE_NAME'
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR 
SELECT NAME FROM SYS.ALL_COLUMNS WHERE OBJECT_ID=(SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME=@TABLE)
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @COLNAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
SET @QUERY='SELECT COUNT(1) FROM '+@TABLE+' WHERE '+@COLNAME+' IS NULL' 
INSERT INTO @TEST EXEC (@QUERY)
IF(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @TEST)>0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @NULLS VALUES ( @TABLE,@COLNAME,'NULL VALUES')
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @NULLS VALUES ( @TABLE,@COLNAME,'NO NULL VALUES')
END
DELETE FROM @TEST
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @COLNAME
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C


SELECT * FROM @NULLS
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find all the specify column is null?

```
;WITH tb(ID,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9)AS(
    SELECT 1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL UNION
    SELECT 2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,3,NULL,NULL UNION
    SELECT 3,1,2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL UNION
    SELECT 4,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL 

)
SELECT * FROM tb
WHERE COALESCE(col1,col2,col3,col3,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9) IS NULL
```

will return id=4

```
ID          col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6        col7        col8        col9
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
4           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

To check which column is NULL with dynamic satement:

```
CREATE TABLE tb(ID INT ,col1 INT ,col2 INT ,col3 INT ,col4 INT ,col5 INT ,col6 INT ,col7 INT ,col8 INT ,col9 INT )
INSERT INTO tb
SELECT 1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL UNION
SELECT 2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,3,NULL,NULL UNION
SELECT 3,1,2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL UNION
SELECT 4,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL 

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max),@sql NVARCHAR(max)
SELECT @cols=ISNULL(@cols+',','')+'('''+c.name+ ''',['+c.name+'])' FROM sys.all_columns AS c WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)='tb'
PRINT @cols
SET @sql='
SELECT ID,c.col_title,CASE WHEN c.col_value IS NULL THEN ''NULL NULL'' ELSE ''HAS VALUE'' END  AS COMMENT FROM dbo.tb
CROSS APPLY(VALUES'+@cols+') c(col_title,col_value)'
PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

```
ID          col_title COMMENT
----------- --------- ---------
1           col1      HAS VALUE
1           col2      NULL NULL
1           col3      NULL NULL
1           col4      NULL NULL
1           col5      NULL NULL
1           col6      NULL NULL
1           col7      NULL NULL
1           col8      NULL NULL
1           col9      NULL NULL
1           ID        HAS VALUE
2           col1      NULL NULL
2           col2      NULL NULL
2           col3      NULL NULL
2           col4      NULL NULL
2           col5      NULL NULL
2           col6      NULL NULL
2           col7      HAS VALUE
2           col8      NULL NULL
2           col9      NULL NULL
2           ID        HAS VALUE
3           col1      HAS VALUE
3           col2      HAS VALUE
3           col3      NULL NULL
3           col4      NULL NULL
3           col5      NULL NULL
3           col6      NULL NULL
3           col7      NULL NULL
3           col8      NULL NULL
3           col9      NULL NULL
3           ID        HAS VALUE
4           col1      NULL NULL
4           col2      NULL NULL
4           col3      NULL NULL
4           col4      NULL NULL
4           col5      NULL NULL
4           col6      NULL NULL
4           col7      NULL NULL
4           col8      NULL NULL
4           col9      NULL NULL
4           ID        HAS VALUE
```